# Why would androidTest not show as a directory type in the dropdown for New Directory?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

When I create a new directory in the src folder, I see test directory options, but I don't see options for creating androidTest directories.  I do see androidTest directory options on my other machine on another app.  What controls this?

This project has custom buildTypes. Could that be related?

Also, if I create the directory named androidTest, it's not recognized as an androidTest directory.

I have androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.6.1"

I don't think they would, but could it be missing because my company blocks it?

Comment: Just to confirm - you have applied the `android` gradle plugin in this project, correct? Because, I think, the android gradle plugin adds the `androidTest` sourceSet

Comment: Yes, I've applied it in the app level build.gradle.  I do not have the plugin applied in the project level build.gradle, but it is included as a classpath dependency.  Is it required to be applied as a plugin in this file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was very difficult to determine but the solution is very simple.  I wasn't aware that by default Android Instrumentation Tests are configured to only run on the 'Debug' variant.  Since my application doesn't have a 'Debug' variant, resources in the androidTest folder did not appear to be recognized as test resources.  By adding the 'testBuildType' setting (below) to my build.gradle:app file, the build variant used for development started recognizing instrumentation tests in the folder.

```
android {
    testBuildType "buildVariantName"
}
```